# How to know if Objective C class cleans memory that it internally created with malloc under ARC?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nsmutabledata

I use `NSMutableData` class in my iOS program. I get unbounded memory growth. I use Automatic Reference Counting. When I used allocation instrument, I saw that `NSMutableData`'s `initWithLength:` method having Malloc calls in order to allocate memory. Under ARC, memory that is allocated by using `malloc` should be released by the programmer because ARC doesn't do anything about it. Since I don't know the implementation of `NSMutableData` class, I can't be sure if the memory allocated by `NSMutableData` is released when `NSMutableData` is released. According to the allocations instrument, that's not the case. Does anyone have any knowledge on this?

Another question is when `NSMutableData` `setLength:` method is called with smaller size than the current size, then does the extra memory get released?

Comment: "Since I don't know the implementation of `NSMutableData` class, I can't be sure if the memory allocated by `NSMutableData` is released when `NSMutableData` is released." The `NSMutableData` class is used so heavily that if it stopped cleaning up after itself one day, someone at Apple would get fired for letting such an enormous bug through. If you do not see `NSMutableData` release its internal data, then something is holding on to a reference to that `NSMutableData` object.

Comment: Do you think that I should put my code in between @autoreleasepool?

Comment: Only if you repeatedly allocate/deallocate autoreleased objects in a loop.

Comment: @neo You would use `@autoreleasepool` to minimize the high water mark of an app (e.g. you have a loop that creates a lot of autorelease objects). But if you're not releasing the memory due to some strong reference, an `@autoreleasepool` won't help.

Comment: How do you know if an object is autoreleased object?